# Capybara with a MongoDB/Mongoid Rails app (without SQL database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, capybara

Is it possible to use Capybara or Webrat in a Rails app which does not rely on ActiveRecord (no SQL database) ? My app is using MongoDB and Mongoid instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Capybara nor webrat rely in any way upon ActiveRecord.